# How to find out the current widget size in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using *Python* and *Tkinter*, and I need to know the current dimensions (width, height) of a widget.

I've tried `somewidget["width"]`, but it returns only a fixed value, and is not updated whenever the widget size changes (e.g. when the window is resized).

Comment: are you sure that your widget is being resized?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use `somewidget.winfo_width()` and `somewidget.winfo_height()` to get the actual widget size, the `somewidget['width']` property is only a hint given to the geometry manager.

Comment: I think you mean "geometry manager", instead of "window manager". And thanks!

Comment: As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040943/in-tkinter-why-winfo-height-always-return-1) *actual* means after the `mainloop()` call . Which in turn means that if one wants to debug widget sizes, one has to place `print` statements somewhere in the event loop (callbacks) or place the info and read it on some widget like label. That's logical if you think about it, but I guess old procedural habits can kick in regardless.

Comment: Don't forget to checkout Apostolos's answer below :)

Answer (score 93):

`somewidget.winfo_width()` and `somewidget.winfo_height()` give 1. You need to update Tk (issue `tk.update()`) before getting these values.

Comment: Thats most important, I waster lot of time debugging this

Comment: I can only say classic debugging stuff again, really this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, I'm getting '1'.  But what do we actually do?  What is  update Tk (issue tk.update())

Comment: @John, `tk.update()` updates the changes made to Tkinter up to this point. Setting new width and height after initializing Tkinter (with `tk = Tk()` or `root = Tk()`, etc.) is such a change.

Comment: @Apostolos, Yes, thanks, I think I'm slowly starting to get it.... 

I found that calling widget.update() was enough to get the real width instead of the puzzling '1'.

I'm guessing that tk.update() will refresh  all 'out-of-date' widgets (whatever that means..., I read it somewhere..?), while widget.update() does the same for just that widget.  I had worried that there was some puzzling change to tk itself, which would be hard to understand.

Comment: yep, future readers please take note of this comment.. it will save a lot of your time debugging as it saved mine!!

Comment: Yes, that's true. I took me too a lot ot time to get to that. And this is only **one** of the many things missing from PY documentations!

Answer (score 16):

You can use the function `somewidget.winfo_reqheight()` for height and `somewidget.winfo_reqwidth()` for width, but first don't forget  to call the update function of the widget you want to know the dimension `somewidget.update()`. If you do not call the update function you will get the default value `1`.

Comment: To add to this, if your `tkinter.Toplevel` parent element (usually produced from `tkinter.Tk()`) is not visible because it was `iconify()`-ed or `withdraw()`-n, you will also just get `1` until you `deiconify()` and `update()` the top window.

Comment: On toplevel window, without .update(), and i just use .winfo_reqwidth or .winfo_reqheight() I got the widget size. I use Python 3.9