# In tkinter, why winfo_height() always return 1?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the most easy example.

```
#py3
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width= 500 , height = 400)
canvas.winfo_height()
#In [4]: canvas.winfo_height()
#Out[4]: 1
```

Comment: See this link https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2013-April/003422.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to [pack](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_pack.htm) the canvas element in the window before getting it's height. The height return is the **actual** height.

```
>>> from tkinter import * 
>>> tk = Tk()
>>> canvas = Canvas(tk, width= 500 , height = 400)
>>> canvas.winfo_height()
1
>>> canvas.pack()
>>> canvas.winfo_height()
402
```

Comment: To be a bit more pedantic, you have to make it visible, which you can do with pack, place, grid, or by embedding it in a text widget or canvas. And you have to have the window drawn on screen either via a call to `update` or by letting `mainloop` do its job.

Comment: Completely an edge case, but I had an issue with getting the winfo_width on a frame that had child widgets deleted and that the geometry manager had re-sized the frame. Using bbox solved the issue as it was still able to get the size before and after the geometry resize of the frame.

Answer (score 14):

If it doesn't work by using `pack()` function, 
you can try to add `canvas.update()` after using `canvas.pack()`.