# Fitting text into a rectangle (width x by height y) with tkinter

Tags: python, fonts, tkinter, widget, pixel

I'm trying to make a program which will fit text into a rectangle (x by y) depending on the text, the font and the font size

Here is the code

```
def fit_text(screen, width, height, text, font):
    measure_frame = Frame(screen) # frame
    measure_frame.pack()
    measure_frame.pack_forget()
    measure = Label(measure_frame, font = font) # make a blank label
    measure.grid(row = 0, column = 0) # put it in the frame

    ##########################################################
    # make a certain number of lines
    ##########################################################

    words = text.split(" ")
    lines = []
    num = 0
    previous = 0
    while num <= len(words):                
        measure.config(text = " ".join(words[previous:num])) # change text
        line_width = measure.winfo_width() # get the width
        print(line_width)
        if line_width >= width: # if the line is now too long
            lines.append(" ".join(words[previous:num - 1])) # add the last vsion which wasn't too long
            previous = num - 1 # previous is now different
        num = num + 1 # next word
    lines.append(" ".join(words[previous:])) # add the rest of it
    return "\n".join(lines)

from tkinter import *    
window = Tk()
screen = Canvas(window)
screen.pack()
text = fit_text(screen, 200, 80, "i want to fit this text into a rectangle which is 200 pixels by 80 pixels", ("Purisa", 12))
screen.create_rectangle(100, 100, 300, 180)
screen.create_text(105, 105, text = text, font = ("Purisa", 12), anchor = "nw")
```

The problem with this is no matter what text is in the label the result from `measure.winfo_width()` is always 1. [Here is where I found this from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950687/how-to-find-out-the-current-widget-size-in-tkinter) but it doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're using the width of a widget, but the width will be 1 until the widget is actually laid out on the screen and made visible, since the actual width depends on a number of factors that aren't present until that happens.

You don't need to put the text in a widget in order to measure it. You can pass a string to `font.measure()` and it will return the amount of space required to render that string in the given font.

For python 3.x you can import the `Font` class like this:

```
from tkinter.font import Font
```

For python 2.x you import it from the `tkFont` module:

```
from tkFont import Font
```

You can then create an instance of `Font` so that you can get information about that font:

```
font = Font(family="Purisa", size=18)
length = font.measure("Hello, world")
print "result:", length
```

You can also get the height of a line in a given font with the `font.metrics()` method, giving it the argument "linespace":

```
height = font.metrics("linespace")
```

Answer (score 1):

The widget will not have a width until it is packed.  You need to put the label into the frame, then pack it, then forget it.

Comment: nothing has changed, whether I pack it or not it still says line_width is 1, the label is also already in the frame

Answer (score 1):

I've actually stumbled across a way of doing this through trial and error

By using `measure.update_idletasks()` it calculates the width properly and it works! Bryan Oakley definitely has a more efficient way of doing it though but I think this method will be useful in other situations

P.S. I wouldn't mind some votes to get a nice, shiny, bronze, self-learner badge ;)