# Is there a conventional, simple way to make the fontsize of text option in a widget to fit?

Tags: python, tkinter

Let's say I have a button widget of arbitrary size,

- is there a conventional way to make its text to fit or let's say
  resize in proportion of the button's new size?

If so what is it?

Comment: I'd say the conventional way is to have the button adapt its size to its content, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing built-in. You can probably make it work, but tkinter is designed to work the other way around: you specify the text and the widget will automatically resize to fit.

Comment: I am using Grid weights and grid method on my widgets to scale. Can I do that for their font sizes?

Comment: @Nae: no, you cannot.

Comment: Hm the best way I came up with was to configure button's fontsize with a resize event. I configure font size with fontSize = event.height // 3 equation but it's not an exact match to that of TK's it seems like. Also atm limited to 1 character only. By any chance would you happen to know [how TK calculates widget size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46982863/7032856)?

Comment: @Nae: tkinter has a function that can return you the number of pixels a given string in a given font takes up. You can see an example of its use here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39311963/7432.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966692/is-there-a-conventional-simple-way-to-make-the-fontsize-of-text-option-in-a-wid) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46982863/how-does-tk-calculate-widget-size-geometry) I came up with the below code:

```
#! Python3

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

def resizeEvent(event, widget):
    #widget.unbind("<Configure>")

    #widget.grid_forget()

    widgetFont = Font(font=widget['font'])
    currentWidth = widget.winfo_width()
    currentHeight = widget.winfo_height()

    while ((widget.winfo_reqwidth() < currentWidth) and (widget.winfo_reqheight() < currentHeight)) and widgetFont['size'] > 1:
        widgetFont['size'] += 1
        widget['font'] = widgetFont

    while ((widget.winfo_reqwidth() > currentWidth) or (widget.winfo_reqheight() > currentHeight)) and widgetFont['size'] > 1:
        widgetFont['size'] -= 1
        widget['font'] = widgetFont

    widget['font'] = widgetFont

    #widget.bind("<Configure>", lambda event,  widget = widget : resizeEvent(event, widget))

def reqWidth(font, widget):
    return font.measure(widget['text'])

def reqHeight(font, widget):
    return font.metrics("linespace")

def font_resizable(widget, isResizable=True):
    if isResizable:
        widget.bind("<Configure>", lambda event,  widget = widget : resizeEvent(event, widget))

    else:
        widget.unbind("<Configure>")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform=True)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform=True)
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform=True)

    button = tk.Entry(frame, text="A")
    button.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, sticky="nsew")

    button1 = tk.Button(frame, text="Dans et üstümde!")
    button1.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=5, sticky="nsew")

    font_resizable(button)
    font_resizable(button1)

    root.mainloop()
```

It's not exactly ideal and misbehaves in some examples, however I want to post this for reference, or a point to begin with at least.