# How does Tk calculate widget size?

Tags: tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

- I want to know what's the exact equation for calculating the widget's
  fit size.

I want to apply that knowledge to dynamically resizing the font of a widget's text, based on the widget's size.

Comment: If you want the exact equation, look at the source code. It's publicly available.

Comment: @BryanOakley This is a valid help but I'm very inexperienced in reading source codes like that. I mean it would help a lot if I actually knew which file to look at. Right now I'm thinking maybe I should try to find a file with either grid or pack in its name.

Comment: You're likely not going to find a single function. The size of a widget depends on its configuration, the font, the system resolution, and the options provided to `pack`, `place`, or `grid`.

Comment: And you don't need to know the equation.  You can determine the size of the widget (or containing widget) using the `winfo width` and `winfo reqwidth` functions.  Then set the size of your font as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Tk GUIs usually work the other way round; the widgets reshape to accommodate their content plus whatever margin and border space is defined. (In Ttk widgets, the style specifies many of those values.) That general requested size is then fed as a suggestion into the geometry management engine. What size a widget actually gets depends on its environment of other widgets as well as what it directly wants, and the rules for that depend on the geometry manager being used; `grid`, `pack` and `place` all have quite different rule engines internally (indeed, `grid` is a complex constraint satisfaction solver).

It is easier to work from the other way round. If you know how much space you have, you can use `font measure` to work out whether your text *in a particular font and size* will fit horizontally; with multiple lines (you don't say if this your scenario or not) you need to measure each line individually. Vertically, you usually just get the overall height from `font metrics` and multiply by the number of lines of text involved; that's what the font rendering engine effectively does internally anyway.

Here's a helper procedure that shows how to do it in the single line case.

```
proc findFontForLine {basefont maxX maxY text} {
    for {set size 2} {$size < 72} {incr size} {
        set testfont [lreplace $basefont 1 1 $size]
        if {[font measure $testfont $text] > $maxX} break
        if {[font metrics $testfont -linespace] > $maxY} break
        set font $testfont
    }
    if {[info exists font]} {
        return $font
    }
    error "could not find reasonable matching font"
}

set sample "This is some sample text"
set maxX 120
set maxY 30
set font [findFontForLine {Arial 5 bold} $maxX $maxY $sample]
puts "Chosen font is '$font'"
```

My system prints `Chosen font is 'Arial 9 bold'` when I run the code, but fonts and displays can be subtly different so your mileage may well vary.

Comment: Recalculating the font size would be something you would do on a `<Configure>` event, which is sent when a widget changes size. If you're doing this, care _must_ be taken to ensure that changing the font size doesn't make the widget resize or you can get a nasty loop condition…

Comment: Also, conversion of the above code to Python is left as an exercise.

Comment: I've written a method for python but it behaves unexpectedly in some examples, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47619271/7032856).