# Automatically resizing of Tkinter labels inside a grid layout

Tags: python, tkinter

I am pretty new in Tkinter and Python, so maybe this will be easy for you guys, but I cannot find a way to solve this...

I want to create something like this:

[image]

So, I am using a grid layout management to create each single cell, and I am storing a label inside each of them.

My current code is:

```
from tkinter import *

class RCP:

    frame = None
    commandsHandle = None

def __init__(self, targets):
    self.n_row = len(targets)
    self.n_col = len(targets[0])
    self.targets = targets
    self.canvasRoot = Tk()

def createGrid(self):
    # Create and configure the root
    Grid.rowconfigure(self.canvasRoot, 0, weight=1)
    Grid.columnconfigure(self.canvasRoot, 0, weight=1)

    # Create and configure the frame
    frame = Frame(self.canvasRoot)
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NESW")

    # Create the grid of commands
    commandsHandle = [[None for i in range(self.n_col)] for j in range(self.n_row)]
    for row_index in range(self.n_row):
        Grid.rowconfigure(frame, row_index, weight=1)
        for col_index in range(self.n_col):
            Grid.columnconfigure(frame, col_index, weight=1)
            commandsHandle[row_index][col_index] = Label(text=self.targets[row_index][col_index])
            commandsHandle[row_index][col_index].grid(row=row_index, column=col_index)

    self.canvasRoot.mainloop()


targets = [['A','B','C','D'],['E','F','G','H'],['I','J','K','L']]
myRCP = RCP(targets)
myRCP.createGrid()
```

, which plots this figure:

[image]

But I have two problems to solve:

- Centering the label's text inside each grid cell
- Automatically resizing the label's text size to fill the entire cell

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _'Automatically resizing the label text size to fill the entire cell'_ is not exactly trivial. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/46966692/7032856.

Comment: What do you mean by _'Centering the label inside each grid cell'_. Labels themselves _are_ the grid cells in the above case. Do you perhaps mean centering their texts? Wouldn't anything else contradict the 2nd part of the question? If the texts are automatically resized to fill, how can they _not_ be centered?

Comment: create minimal working example with your problem

Comment: @Nae, I understand what you are talking about. Yes, it is a bit redundant, but the 2nd part would not contradict the first one if the cells are rectangles (for instance, because the user has previously resized the window). In that case, I want their texts centered, and resized in order to fill the smallest size of the rectangular grid.

Comment: @furas, I edited the post in order to detail the Python code of an example and I have uploaded the resulting image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is by no means a perfect solution (and gets terrible performance on my machine) but here you go:

```
from tkinter import *

text = [['A','B','C','D'],['E','F','G','H'],['I','J','K','L'],['M', 'N', 'O', 'P'],['Q','R','S','T'],['U','V','W','X'],['Y','Z','1','2'],['3','4','5','6']]

root = Tk()

for c, i in enumerate(text):
    Grid.rowconfigure(root, c, weight=1)
    for a, b in enumerate(i):
        Label(root, text=b, font=('', 10)).grid(row=c, column=a)
        Grid.columnconfigure(root, a, weight=1)

class Resize:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.update()
        self.startsize = (root.winfo_width(),root.winfo_height())
        self.root.bind("<Configure>", self.on_resize)
    def on_resize(self, event):
        for i in self.root.winfo_children():
            i.config(font=('', int(10*((((self.root.winfo_width() * root.winfo_height()) - (self.startsize[0] * self.startsize[1]))/(self.startsize[0] * self.startsize[1]))+1))))

Resize(root)
root.mainloop()
```

To answer your queries:

---

**Centering the label's text inside each grid cell**

Widgets default to the centre of the grid "cell", what I'm assuming you mean is having them evenly spread out over the window. This is accomplished using the commands:

```
Grid.rowconfigure(root, c, weight=1)
```

and

```
Grid.columnconfigure(root, a, weight=1)
```

Here, we are giving every grid `column` and `row` an equal weight of `1`. Meaning that every `column` will share any extra x-axis space that the window gains and every `row` will share any extra y-axis space that the window gains. Which means that every "cell" shares space with the other children of the window equally, so they're spread out evenly.

---

**Automatically resizing the label's text size to fill the entire cell**

In order to achieve this, we need to calculate the size increase of the window compared to its original size. So we use this long equation:

```
((((self.root.winfo_width() * root.winfo_height()) - (self.startsize[0] * self.startsize[1]))/(self.startsize[0] * self.startsize[1]))+1)
```

To make this more readable it's the same as the below:

> (((Current window x-axis * Current window y-axis) - (Starting window x-axis * Starting window y-axis)) / (Starting window x-axis * Starting window y-axis)) + 1

Or

> ((Current window area - Original window area) / Original Window area) + 1

What this results in is a percentage increase of the area of the window taking into account the original size of the window.

Meaning that if the window increased in size by 10% compared to its original size then we would end up with `1.1` as the outcome of the equation. We then multiply the original font size (10 for convenience's sake) by the outcome of the equation (`1.1`) to get our new font size of 11, which is 10% bigger than 10, meaning our font size scales with the window.

Unfortunately, I haven't figured out a way to have the program detect when a label's font increases so much it forces the text outside of the bounds of grid "cell". This means that when expanding the window in the x-axis we end up in a situation where the vertical height of the text causes parts of the letters to be cut off. I do not have a way of resolving this at present. I'll update my answer if I find a way.