# How to resize all widgets and text when window is resized

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, resize

Now I now that there are already tons of similar questions out there but none of them have worked and many are outdated. From what I've gathered people are always recommending the `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure`, but that doesn't deal with text sizes. Here's a simple example:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()

l1 = Label(root, text="This", borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
l1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='NSEW')

l2 = Label(root, text="That", borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
l2.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='NSEW')

for i in range(1):
    root.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
for i in range(2):
    root.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I found [this site](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/325835/tkinter-resize-text-widget-along-with-root-window) but it's from 2010 and copy pasting it got me no results (after dealing with import names of course)

Comment: Tkinter has no feature that will automatically change font sizes for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this will work:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkFont
root=Tk()

my_font = tkFont.Font(size=10)
def resizer(event):
   if event.width in range(200,225):
      my_font.configure(size=10)   
   elif event.width in range(226,300):
      my_font.configure(size=20)
   elif event.width > 300:
      my_font.configure(size=30)

l1 = Label(root, text="This", borderwidth=2, relief="groove", font=my_font)
l1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='NSEW')

l2 = Label(root, text="That", borderwidth=2, relief="groove", font=my_font)
l2.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='NSEW')

for i in range(1):
    root.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
for i in range(2):
    root.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

root.bind("<Configure>", resizer)
root.mainloop()
```

You can change the `range(200,225)` etc. To suit your needs, and in extra `elif` if required.

This was found from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48733923/python-tkinter-text-size-not-resizing/48735057). And edited to fit in within this script.

Comment: Hm I some mathematical function that maps `event.width` to a desired font size would complete this solution and negate the need for a bunch of hardcoded else if statements. However it probably still wouldn’t be as smooth as those dynamic web pages. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @NathanTew As Bryan Oakley said, they is no tkinter feature to this. I believe this would be your best option.